# Send email via Microsoft Graph API using Python with service principal

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-service-principal

I have the service principal set up in Azure portal with Mail.Send access, I have client_id, tenant_id, client_secret information of that service principal. I am using the below code to send email, but I am getting errors.

So, in the graph url, if I use `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me`. I am getting authentication error. If use this url `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_id}/sendMail`, in place of `user_id`, I have tried the below options, but everything failed and given **Invalid user** error. Help me to resolve this.

for user_id, used the below options,

1. client_id
2. tenant_id
3. app:client_id@tenant_id
4. app:tenant_id@client_id

```
import requests
import json
import msal

# Define your Microsoft 365 email details
recipient_email = "receiver@example.com"
subject = "Email subject"
message_body = "Email message body"

# Your application (client) ID and client secret obtained from Azure AD
client_id = "90xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
client_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

# Tenant ID (directory ID)
tenant_id = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx"

# Microsoft Graph API endpoint to send an email as the application (service principal)
graph_url = f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{client_id}/sendMail"

# Create a confidential client application
app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
    client_id=client_id,
    authority=f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}",
    client_credential=client_secret,
)

# Get an access token
result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"])
access_token = result.get("access_token")


# Create the email message
email_message = {
    "message": {
        "subject": subject,
        "body": {
            "contentType": "Text",
            "content": message_body,
        },
        "toRecipients": [
            {
                "emailAddress": {
                    "address": recipient_email
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}

# Convert the message to JSON format
email_data = json.dumps(email_message)

# Send the email
response = requests.post(
    graph_url,
    headers={
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    data=email_data,
)

# Check the response status code
if response.status_code == 202:
    print("Email sent successfully!")
else:
    print(f"Failed to send email. Status code: {response.status_code}")
    print(response.text)
```

Invalid user error I got for using client_id or tenant_id or both combined,

```
**For client_id or tenant_id:**
Failed to send email. Status code: 404
{"error":{"code":"ErrorInvalidUser","message":"The requested user 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx' is invalid."}}

**For both combined:**
Failed to send email. Status code: 404
{"error":{"code":"ErrorInvalidUser","message":"The requested user 'app:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx' is invalid."}}

**For using graph url with /me:**
Failed to send email. Status code: 400
{"error":{"code":"BadRequest","message":"/me request is only valid with delegated authentication flow.","innerError":{"date":"2023-09-29T15:44:45","request-id":"xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx","client-request-id":"xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx"}}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The error occurred as you are passing  **`client_id`** or **`tenant_id`** in **graph url** instead of user ID or UPN.

I registered one Azure AD application and granted **`Mail.Send`** API permission of **Application** type as below:

[image]

When I ran your code in my environment by passing **`client_id`** in graph url, I too got **same error** as below:

```py
import requests
import json
import msal

# Define your Microsoft 365 email details
recipient_email = "receiver@example.com"
subject = "Email subject"
message_body = "Email message body"

# Your application (client) ID and client secret obtained from Azure AD
client_id = "xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
client_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

# Tenant ID (directory ID)
tenant_id = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx"

# Microsoft Graph API endpoint to send an email as the application (service principal)
graph_url = f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{client_id}/sendMail"

# Create a confidential client application
app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
    client_id=client_id,
    authority=f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}",
    client_credential=client_secret,
)

# Get an access token
result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"])
access_token = result.get("access_token")


# Create the email message
email_message = {
    "message": {
        "subject": subject,
        "body": {
            "contentType": "Text",
            "content": message_body,
        },
        "toRecipients": [
            {
                "emailAddress": {
                    "address": recipient_email
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}

# Convert the message to JSON format
email_data = json.dumps(email_message)

# Send the email
response = requests.post(
    graph_url,
    headers={
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    data=email_data,
)

# Check the response status code
if response.status_code == 202:
    print("Email sent successfully!")
else:
    print(f"Failed to send email. Status code: {response.status_code}")
    print(response.text)
```

**Response:**

[image]

> To **resolve** the error, you need to pass either *ID* or *UPN* of **user** having **active** Office 365 license.

When I ran the same code by passing **user's UPN** in graph url, I got response like this:

```py
import requests
import json
import msal

# Define your Microsoft 365 email details
recipient_email = "sri@xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com"
subject = "Demo mail"
message_body = "Hello Sri!"

# Your application (client) ID and client secret obtained from Azure AD
client_id = "xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
client_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

# Tenant ID (directory ID)
tenant_id = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx"

# User's UPN
user_upn  =  "xxxx_rk@M3xxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com"

# Microsoft Graph API endpoint to send an email as the application (service principal)
graph_url = f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_upn}/sendMail"

# Create a confidential client application
app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
    client_id=client_id,
    authority=f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}",
    client_credential=client_secret,
)

# Get an access token
result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"])
access_token = result.get("access_token")


# Create the email message
email_message = {
    "message": {
        "subject": subject,
        "body": {
            "contentType": "Text",
            "content": message_body,
        },
        "toRecipients": [
            {
                "emailAddress": {
                    "address": recipient_email
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}

# Convert the message to JSON format
email_data = json.dumps(email_message)

# Send the email
response = requests.post(
    graph_url,
    headers={
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    data=email_data,
)

# Check the response status code
if response.status_code == 202:
    print("Email sent successfully!")
else:
    print(f"Failed to send email. Status code: {response.status_code}")
    print(response.text)
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **confirm** that, I checked the same in user's Outlook where mail sent successfully as below:

[image]

Here, you are authenticating as a **service principal** by generating access token using **client credentials** flow where there is no user interaction.

With this token, service principal will send mail **on-behalf of** specified user.

Comment: How can I find users ID or UPN? What does it mean Microsoft 365 license? How can I find if any particular user is having Microsoft 365 license?

Comment: Go to Azure Portal -> Microsoft Entra ID -> Users -> Select user -> Licenses. Check [this](https://i.imgur.com/82giehJ.png)

Comment: To find User's ID or UPN, click on User's Overview page like [this](https://i.imgur.com/7NkuJYl.png)

Comment: when I checked,for my account,having license of Microsoft 365 F3.The identities shows as organizationName365.onmicrosoft.com,but the user principal name looks like username@organizationName.com.In place of user_upn in your code, I tried with username@organizationName.com, also tried with username@organizationName365.onmicrosoft.com, both gave the same error Failed to send email. Status code: 403
{"error":{"code":"ErrorAccessDenied","message":"Access is denied.Check credentials and try again."}}. Please refer the screenshots here https://imgur.com/YYz0YNs , https://imgur.com/veZAbX1

Comment: also tried with object ID shown in the user page, which also gave the same error. please help me what I am missing here.

Comment: Could you try decoding your **access token** by pasting it in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms) website and check `roles` claim?

Comment: there is no claim called ```roles```, below is the output I got, attached the screenshot, could not paste it here https://imgur.com/krVUFE4

Comment: Then the issue might be in granting API permissions. You either added `Mail.Send` permission of **Delegated** type or missed granting **admin consent** to added permission.

Comment: Could you include the **API permissions** snip of your application from Azure Portal?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255506/discussion-between-sridevi-and-beginner).

Comment: Is that possible to send an email with service principal credentials, but the API permissions are delegated type, Mail.Send, Mail.SendShared.

Comment: No, it's not possible. You need to assign `Mail.Send` permission of **Application** type only to send an email with service principal.